# Errors installing CUDA back-end (or cudarray) in Python in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycuda

I am trying to follow the instructions to install CUDA (https://github.com/andersbll/cudarray).

I am able to install the cudarray python package WITHOUT CUDA back-end following the instruction. The installation seems to be successful. When "pip freeze" I can see "cudarray==0.1.dev0" on the list.

Though what I really want to set up is WITH CUDA back-end and am having troubles.

Question #1: The instruction suggests that the INSTALL_PREFIX should be "/usr/local" and CUDA_PREFIX should be "/usr/local/cuda". My python is installed via Data/Anaconda, and the path to my site package is "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Dato\Dato Launcher\Lib\site-packages". Does it mean my INSTALL_PREFIX should be set to "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local" and my CUDA_PREFIX should be "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local/cuda"?

Question #2: From the installation instruction, it says I have to type "make" then "make install". But I don't know where and when to execute these commands. What I tried was cmd (into terminal) > cd (to the setup.py path under the cudarray-master folder) > make. Then I got "'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

===========================================================================

Edits/updates:
Since my question I have installed GnuWin32, then I add its bin path as an environment variable.

After I cd to the location and type make, I got this error:

```
C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\DeepArtist_Python\cudarray-master>make
g++ -O3 -fPIC -Wall -Wfatal-errors -D_FORCE_INLINES -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -c -o src/nnet/conv_bc01_matmul.o src/nnet/conv_bc01_matmul.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -O3 -fPIC -Wall -Wfatal-errors -D_FORCE_INLINES -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -c -o src/nnet/conv_bc01_matmul.o src/nnet/conv_bc01_matmul.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [src/nnet/conv_bc01_matmul.o] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question; however, it should provide insight into your issue or you can directly follow the outlined steps to get PyCUDA installed:
I have recently (within the past 4 months) successfully completed a PyCUDA install on my Win 10 machine. The steps I followed including links to the requisite python and PyCUDA libraries can be found here:

[Win 10 PyCUDA install instructions](https://github.com/kdkoadd/Win10-PyCUDA-Install/blob/master/PyCUDAWin10Config.ipynb)

Comment: Got a question for you, I am trying to follow the steps, but from step 1 to 8, it looks like it's trying to set up VS 2013; but in step 9, it is asking you to add env variable paths for VS 2012. Should I change the paths to 2013 instead?

Comment: Never mind I got it working following the exact steps. Thanks.